# Simulate Tapping Done Button

Tags: iphone, ios, uiwebview

I have a UIWebView and when I have the keyboard up after entering in data, I want to be able to programmatically dismiss the keyboard, and hit the return key to load the next page. Is there anyway to do this?

Some Ideas:
• Faking a tap on the Done Button
• Sending a Carriage return via JavaScript

I have tried these but haven't been successful.

Comment: Is the done button in UIWebView or not?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can use the `[UIWebView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString]` method to achieve it.

You can use the above method to exec a javascript, the script can be a submit form command. Here is some example:

```
NSString js = @"document.forms[0].submit()";
[self.webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:js];
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the usual [trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804563/how-to-hide-the-keyboard-when-empty-area-is-touched-on-iphone) for hiding a keyboard?

You could try `resignFirstResponder` on the webview.

Comment: yes, but I need to submit the web form, like the done button in the UIWebView does.

Comment: a simple form submit will not work either, because it is not always a form. It needs to simulate the exact code that the done button does within the web view.