# iOS 5: Hide keyboard in UITableViewController with static cells and textfields

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview

I'm developing an app that has an UITableViewController with **static cells**. Those static cells are custom ones and have UITextFields within them. If the user touches one of those textfields, the keyboard pops up. So, after that, what I need to do is to be able to dismiss the keyboard by touching anything on the background. By anything I mean the table view background, its cells and the content of those cells (like the text fields for example).

I used to do this by placing a View in the front of all my other subviews and capture the Touch Inside Up event to dismiss the keyboard. Unfortunately, I can't do this this time because I'm using a UITableViewController and I can't switch it back to an UIViewController because I've already done a lot of work with those static cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the answer myself. What I need to do was just place programatically an UIView in the foreground and do as I said in the original post. I couldn't do this before because I was trying to achieve that from the Interface Builder.

Answer (score 1):

```
 -(void)touchesBegan: (NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
    
[yourTextField resignFirstResponder];
 }
```

Try that.

**EDIT**

Hi,

I've got your answer :

```
-(BOOL)isFirstResponder
```

When you enter something in a text field, it becomes first responder and the keyboard appears. You know that the keyboard is active if [textField isFirstReponder] returns YES.

You may also see that link.may be it will help you.

[how to hide the keyboard when empty area is touched on iphone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/804563/how-to-hide-the-keyboard-when-empty-area-is-touched-on-iphone)

Comment: It works just when I touch one cell... but what I need is to dismiss the Keyboard when the user touches the background of the tableview, its cells or any other subview it touches (including others textviews).